# stepwise regression returns an empty model (no predictors chosen)

Tags: r, regression

I have a numerical (continuous) dependent variable and more than 40 independent variables. (2 numerical, 3 categorical and the rest are dummy variables). I tried to do both forward and backward selection to have a smaller number of predictor variables in my model:

```
nullmod <- lm(y ~ 1, data = df)
fullmod <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 .... + x40, data = df)
reg1A <- step(nullmod, scope = list(lower = nullmod, upper = fullmod),
              direction = "forward")
```

I also did the same with direction = "backward

the result says that my model is best with none of the variables added! while when I do multiple regression with a few of my variables, I get pretty significant results. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe the first few variables failed, try direction = "backward"

Comment: I did both. I should have explained. sorry.

Comment: Would you be able to produce a reproducible example (with either a simulated dataset, or publicly available one)?

Comment: I ran your code with simulated data, it should work